# Are there any spell casting hotkeys for Clash of Clans Builder Base attacks?

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-of-clans-builder-base

New CoC player here. I play the Builder Base a lot and just upgraded to BH5.

I notice that, when attacking, there are numbers in front of the troops’ ability casting bars. I play on a tablet so I actually tried connecting a keyboard, but when I press 1234 or any combination with modifiers, it didn’t work like that.

It wasn’t that much of a problem previously, but now with the Cannon Cart if I switch to Mortar Mode a split second late it runs itself in range of enemy cannons. Therefore, being able to change to Mortar Mode in time is a big deal and tapping it sometimes just isn’t as easy as using hotkeys. How can this be done?